# script to log idle time of xserver

Tags: command-line, scripts, xorg, automation

The following is a script to calculate the idle time of a machine. The script is supposed to check xserver idle time at a time interval of 1 minutes and log the result to a location via cronjob. But that is not working as i expected. It is not reporting the idle time even if the machine idles for more than the idle time limit assigned.

The time limit in the example is 1 minute. It is just a dummy time set for asking this question and checking without wasting time.

Can anybody help ?

```
#!/bin/bash
timeinmsec="$(xprintidle)"
timeinmin="$(($timeinmsec / 60000))"
if [[ "$timeinmin" -gt 1 ]]
then
        echo "$timeinmin Minutes idle time reported" >> /home/user/log.txt;
        echo $(date '+%X') >> /home/user/log.txt;
        echo "$line" >> /home/user/log.txt;
else
        echo "No idle time reported" >> /home/user/log.txt;
        echo $(date '+%X') >> /home/user/log.txt;
        echo "$line" >> /home/user/log.txt;
fi
```

Output i get

```
No idle time reported
05:24:01 PM

No idle time reported
05:25:01 PM

No idle time reported
05:26:01 PM

No idle time reported
05:27:01 PM
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the raw data ?  `echo $timeminsec` ? Or that the process, running from crontab, don't have an active xserver  session?

Comment: @SorenA Thanks for the comment. I fixed the issue.. i had to export the DISPLAY as it is being run by cronjob. Your comment lead me to check that. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue.I had to add `export DISPLAY=:0` at the top of the script as this task being run by cronjob and its calling xserver.